# How can I define the last element in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, sorting, foreach

This is my for each loop

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
}
```

The result is:

```
one
four
end
three
two
```

I want now that the $key `end` is always at the end. Is this possible?

Something like

```
  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if($key == "end"){
           echo $key as last;
        } else {
           echo $key;
        }
    }
```

So that the result is

```
one
four
three
two
end
```

Comment: why not adding the rigid value after the loop to the same array? _$array[] = "end"_

Comment: what is a rigid?

Comment: i mean a static value ;)

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Is "end" always there?

Comment: yes indeed it is

Comment: why do you even need an "end" value, if it's always there, in all circumstances? What practical purpose does it serve?

Comment: @ADyson No I did mean, end SHOULD always be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentined in my comment, simply add the static value to the end of your `array`

```
array_push($row, "end");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can create a custom function , pass your array to a function. Inside that function you could filter the data the way you want .I have created formatRow() function , it just remove the key that you want at last from the array , and insert it again , as the new value are always inserted at end of array , you get the desired output

```
    $row = array(

    'one'=>"data",
    'four'=>"data",
    'end'=>"enddata",
    'three'=>"data",
    'two'=>"data",

    );

    $formatted_row = formatRow($row,'end');

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($formatted_row);


    //output 

    // array(5) {
    //   ["one"]=>
    //   string(4) "data"
    //   ["four"]=>
    //   string(4) "data"
    //   ["three"]=>
    //   string(4) "data"
    //   ["two"]=>
    //   string(4) "data"
    //   ["end"]=>
    //   string(7) "enddata"
    // }



function formatRow ($row,$key_that_you_need_last) {
    if (array_key_exists($key_that_you_need_last,$row)) {
            $value = $row["$key_that_you_need_last"];
        unset($row["$key_that_you_need_last"]);
        $row["$key_that_you_need_last"] = $value;
    }
    return $row;  
}
```

If you want to achieve more ,these are the links that you might wanna go through. 
[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: But why the overload?

Comment: beacuse as Jarla asked ,He wanted to shift The value of associated array at the end that has the key, end .The  array_push($row, "end"); you used will just insert element to last position but will not remove the key , if already present